# New York Times API ajax jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to do an ajax JSONP request from new york times API. But the following code keeps giving me errors and won't return anything. I am really new to jquery especially ajax formatting. could somebody please help out??

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'GET',
    'url': 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch',
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    'callback': '',
    data: {
        'q': seaString,
        'response-format': "jsonp",
        'api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'callback': 'svc_search_v2_articlesearch'
    },
    'success': function(data, textStats, XMLHttpRequest) {
        // passed function object for data processing
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and new york times api specification are in this link:

http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2#examples

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, should work for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch',
    dataType: json,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        q: seaString,
        response-format: 'jsonp',
        api-key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        callback: 'svc_search_v2_articlesearch'
    }),
    success: function(data, textStats, XMLHttpRequest) {
        // passed function object for data processing
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("whoops ! something went wrng. Time go SO.")
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! really appreciate it. When I try using the modified code, the following errors show up.  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" and "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes in success key.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around, the following code gives me a good result without cross-orgin errors from getJSON request. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
$.ajax({

    'type': 'GET',
    'url': 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json',
    data: {
        'q': queryString,
        'response-format': "jsonp",
        'api-key': nytApiKey,
        'callback': 'svc_search_v2_articlesearch'
    },
        success: function(data) {
        // passed function object for data processing 
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```